# Accessing object initialized in one thread from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have some code that performs feature detection on an image. The feature detection algorithm has some user-defined parameters. I'm working on some code to scan over different parameters choices to see how it affects the output, and I want to use multiple threads so that the scan points can run in parallel. So I have a Scanner class with the following data members and methods:

```
class Scanner
{
protected:
   int m_maxThreads,m_activeThreads;
   boost::thread_group m_threadpool;
   boost::mutex m_mtx;
   ImSeries* m_data;
   FileManager* m_fileManager;

public:
   Scanner();
   void run(some args);
   void run_point(some args);
}
```

where the ImSeries object contains a series of images represented as 2D arrays, and the FileManager object contains a list of groups of image files and has a loadNext() method that creates and returns a new ImSeries object (on the heap) from the next group of files. The run_point() method is supposed to run the feature detection on m_data using a specific set of parameters passed as arguments, and the run() method contains the following code:

```
void Scanner::run(some args)
{
   //some stuff
   m_data = m_fileManager->loadNext();
   while(m_data){
      for(){ //several for loops here looping over parameter combinations
         while(m_activeThreads == m_maxThreads) boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(60000));
         m_mtx.lock();
         m_threadpool.create_thread(boost::bind(&Scanner::run_point,this,args));
         m_activeThreads++;
         m_mtx.unlock();
      }
      m_threadpool.join_all(); //finish parameter scan on this image series before loading the next one
      delete m_data;
      m_data = m_fileManager->loadNext();
   }
}
```

But when I try to run this, I get a seg fault as soon as run_point() tries to call a method of m_data. I ran this in gdb and printed the value of m_data in the main thread and the first worker thread launched and got this result:

> main thread: m_data = 0x8e9900
>
> worker thread: m_data = 0x1

I don't understand why m_data is not the same in the worker thread. What's even more confusing is that m_fileManager does have the expected behavior:

> main thread: m_fileManager = 0x8aa700
>
> worker thread m_fileManager = 0x8aa700

Why should one of these be preserved across threads and the other not?

Comment: Provide [MCV example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you should put the whole implementation of `run` and `run_point` methods.

Comment: Why are you locking around the thread creation? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: m_activeThreads is decremented by the worker threads when they finish. The lock is just there to make sure two threads aren't trying to change m_activeThreads at the same time. I could have moved the lock down one line so that it's just before 'm_activeThreads++', but it shouldn't matter that it comes before the thread creation since it only affects other threads when they're also trying to obtain that lock.